# Matching two datasets with different daterange and different length

Tags: python, pandas, matching

I have two csv-files with different dateformats and lenght.

First, I load these two files:

```
frameA = pd.read_csv("fileA.csv", dtype=str, delimiter=";", skiprows = None)
```

File A has 102216 rows x 3 columns, ends at `01.07.2012 00:00`. Date and Time are **in one column**. Head looks like this:

```
Date                 Buy     Sell
0  01.08.2009 00:15    0       0
1  01.08.2009 00:30    0       0
2  01.08.2009 00:45    0       0
3  01.08.2009 01:00    0       0
4  01.08.2009 01:15    0       0
```

.

```
frameB = pd.read_csv("fileB.csv", dtype=str, delimiter=";", skiprows = None)
```

File B has 92762 rows x 4 columns, ends at `22.07.2012 00:00`. Date and Time are **separate**. Head looks like this:

```
        Date    Time         Buy           Sell
0  01.08.2009   01:00          0              0
1  01.08.2009   02:00          0              0
2  01.08.2009   03:00          0              0
3  01.08.2009   04:00          0             10
4  01.08.2009   05:00          0             32
```

How can I match these datas like this:

```
                     Buy A   Sell A   Buy B   Sell B
0  01.08.2009 00:15    0       0       0       0
1  01.08.2009 00:30    0       0       0       0
```

Both has to start and to end with the same date and the frequency has to be 15 min.

**How can I get this?** What should I do first?

Answer (score 1):

OK, first thing is to make sure both df's have datetimes as dtypes for the first df:

```
frameA = pd.read_csv("fileA.csv", dtype=str, delimiter=";", skiprows = None, parse_dates=['Date'])
```

and for the other df:

```
frameB = pd.read_csv("fileB.csv", dtype=str, delimiter=";", skiprows = None, parse_dates=[['Date','Time']])
```

Now I would reset the minute value of the first df like so:

```
In [149]:

df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(minute=0))
df
Out[149]:
                     Date Buy Sell
index                             
0     2009-01-08 04:00:00   0    0
1     2009-01-08 04:00:00   0    0
2     2009-01-08 04:00:00   0    0
3     2009-01-08 05:00:00   0    0
4     2009-01-08 05:00:00   0    0
```

Now we can merge the dfs:

```
In [150]:

merged = df.merge(df1, left_on=['Date'], right_on=['Date_Time'], how='left',suffixes=[' A', ' B'])
merged
Out[150]:
                 Date Buy A Sell A           Date_Time Buy B Sell B
0 2009-01-08 04:00:00     0      0 2009-01-08 04:00:00     0     10
1 2009-01-08 04:00:00     0      0 2009-01-08 04:00:00     0     10
2 2009-01-08 04:00:00     0      0 2009-01-08 04:00:00     0     10
3 2009-01-08 05:00:00     0      0 2009-01-08 05:00:00     0     32
4 2009-01-08 05:00:00     0      0 2009-01-08 05:00:00     0     32
```

Obviously replace `df`, `df1` with `frameA` and `frameB` in your case

Comment: here's a little trick to normalize the times: df['Date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(minute=0,second=0).

Comment: Okay. After working on some other things, I tried to run it (the pd.read_csv-lines from EdChum) and I get the error: 'Date' is not in list  What should I do?

Comment: @EP1986 subsitute the name for whatever the name of your column is, or use the ordinal position e.g. zero-based `parse_dates=[1]` if the second column is your date column

Comment: Great. You are a fast guy!:-) Now, I have e.g. four times `09:00:00`. But I need 09:00:00, 09:15:00, 09:30:00 and 09:45:00 for the existing values. Is there a trick/easy code for that?

Comment: No there is no trick, locate the rows where you have those values and update them, so you could do something like `idx = df.loc[df['date'] == '09:00:00'].index` then loop over the indices and set the values to your desired values e.g. for i in idx: df.loc[i, 'date'] = '09:00:00'` ...etc. you should be able to figure it out hopefully

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could do is set the date to the index:

As the answer above correctly states, the first step is to parse them into an identical format.

```
frameA = pd.read_csv("fileA.csv", dtype=str, delimiter=";", skiprows = None, parse_dates=['Date'])

frameB = pd.read_csv("fileB.csv", dtype=str, delimiter=";", skiprows = None, parse_dates=[['Date','Time']])
```

After including the data into the arrays, as shown above, we can set the index to the data to guide the merger:

```
frameA.index = frameA['Date']
frameB.index = frameB['Date']
```

Then, they will merge on the exact same index, and since they have similar columns ('Buy', 'Sell'), we need to specify suffixes for the merger:

merge = frameA.join(frameB, lsuffix = ' A', rsuffix = ' B')

The result would look exactly like this.

```
                     Buy A   Sell A   Buy B   Sell B
0  01.08.2009 00:15    0       0       0       0
1  01.08.2009 00:30    0       0       0       0
```

The advantage of this approach is that if your second data set ('Buy B', 'Sell B') is missing times present in the first slot, the merger will still work and you won't have data misassigned to the improper time. Let's say we have an arbitrary numerical index from 1-10000 for both, and the second dataframe is missing 3 values (index only goes from 1-9997). This will cause a shift, and then we improperly assign values to the wrong index is the one guiding the joining.

Here, as long as the dataframe guiding the joining is longer than the second dataframe, we won't lose any data, and we will never poorly assign it to the wrong index.

So for example:

```
if len(frameA.index) >= len(frameB.index):
    merge = frameA.join(frameB)
else:
    print 'Missing Values, define your own function here'
    quit()
```

EDIT:

Another way to make sure all data is reported, regardless of whether it occurs in both columns would be to define a new dataframe with a unique list of dates present in both dataframes, and use that to guide the merger.

For example,

```
unique_index = sorted(list(set(frameA.index.tolist() + frameB.index.tolist())))
```

Defines a unique index by summing both index lists, turning it to a set, and back to a list. Sets remove all redundant values, so you have a unique list, and the list is sorted since sets are not ordered.

Then, you merge the dataframes:

```
merge = pd.DataFrame(index = unique_index)
merge = merge.join(frameA)
merge = merge.join(frameB, lsuffix = ' A', rsuffix = ' B')
```

Just make sure to export it with the index ON, or redefine the index as a column (exporting to a csv or an excel sheet automatically has the index on unless you turn it off, so just be sure not to set index = False).

And then any missing data from your 'Buy A', 'Sell A' columns that is present in 'Buy B', 'Sell B' will be 'nan', as will be data missing from 'Buy B', 'Sell B' that is present in 'Buy A', 'Sell A'.

Comment: I run your code until `would exactly look like this:`, but now I have the right timeformat like 09:15:00, but still I have two time/date_columns like in the answer of EdChum. Whats going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are setting your date/times to be the index and that they are moved over?

One way to check is to print the dataframes to file before and after, or to run this in interactive mode. If they are truly moved to the index, they should only show up on the left and should not have an associated column. Then with the merger, they should merge on this index, and there should be only one index.

Another way is you can always just drop the column after everything is done:

df.drop([column], axis=1)